# How can I colorize slider track segments between divisions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, colors, slider, division

I'm quite new to Flutter, so that's why currently I can't understand how can I customize the slider track to colorize each segment by separate color between divisions, please help to achieve the same design as is on the screenshot below.
[custom slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lhfc.png)

Code snippet with colors as well:

```
final List<Color> _divisionColors = [
  Color(0xff8DF5DE),
  Color(0xffA8F58C),
  Color(0xffFCEC74),
  Color(0xffFCD376),
  Color(0xffFDB272),
  Color(0xffE27E5A),
];
```

Comment: Maybe It’s only me, but I can't see your image it’s not loading

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is very late. I hope this helps others.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ColoredSlider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColoredSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ColoredSliderState createState() => _ColoredSliderState();
}

class _ColoredSliderState extends State<ColoredSlider> {
  double _value = 3;
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _loadImage();
  
  }

 _loadImage() async {
    ByteData byData = await rootBundle.load('assets/Triangle.png');
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(byData.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes, targetWidth: 30, targetHeight: 30);
    ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    myShape = ImageThumbShape(image: image);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 55,
      width: 340,
      child: SliderTheme(
        data: SliderThemeData(
         thumbShape: myShape,
          overlayShape: const RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 10),
          trackHeight: 16, // Adjust the track height
          trackShape: CustomTrackShape(), // Set the custom track shape
        ),
        child: Slider(
          value: _value,
          min: 1,
          max: 5,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _value = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadImage() async {
    ByteData byData = await rootBundle.load('assets/Triangle.png');
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(byData.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes, targetWidth: 30, targetHeight: 30);
    ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    myShape = ImageThumbShape(image: image);
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class CustomTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset? offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isDiscrete,
  }) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(
      offset!.dx,
      offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - sliderTheme.trackHeight!) / 2,
      parentBox.size.width,
      sliderTheme.trackHeight!,
    );
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    Animation<double>? enableAnimation,
    Offset? thumbCenter,
    bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isDiscrete,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    Offset? secondaryOffset,
  }) {
    if (sliderTheme.trackHeight == null || sliderTheme.trackHeight! <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );

    final Paint paint = Paint();
    final sliderDivisions = 5; // Your slider division

    // Calculate the segment width
    final double segmentWidth = trackRect.width / sliderDivisions;

    // Paint colored segments between divisions
    for (int index = 0; index < sliderDivisions; index++) {
      final double startX = trackRect.left + (index * segmentWidth);
      final double endX = trackRect.left + ((index + 1) * segmentWidth);

      final Rect segmentRect = Rect.fromLTRB(startX, trackRect.top, endX, trackRect.bottom);

      // Set different colors for segments
      if (index == 0) {
        paint.color = Color(0xffF4D11D);
      } else if (index == 1) {
        paint.color = Color(0xffD1D231);
      } else if (index == 2) {
        paint.color = Color(0xffB3D342);
      } else if (index == 3) {
        paint.color = Color(0xff9CD450);
      } else if (index == 4) {
        paint.color = Color(0xff83D55E);
      } else if (index == 5) {
        paint.color = Color(0xffF4D11D);
      } else if (index == 6) {
        paint.color = Colors.green;
      }
      // Draw rounded rectangle
      context.canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          segmentRect,
          topLeft: index == 0 ? Radius.circular(sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 2) : Radius.zero,
          topRight: (index == 5 - 1) ? Radius.circular(sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 2) : Radius.zero,
          bottomLeft: index == 0 ? Radius.circular(sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 2) : Radius.zero,
          bottomRight: (index == 5 - 1) ? Radius.circular(sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 2) : Radius.zero,
        ),
        paint,
      );

      // Draw vertical white line
      if (index < sliderDivisions - 1) {
        final double lineX = startX + segmentWidth;
        context.canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(lineX, trackRect.top),
          Offset(lineX, trackRect.bottom),
          Paint()
            ..color = Colors.white
            ..strokeWidth = 2.0, // Line Width
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

// Below code, helps to convert image to a thumb shape

```
class ImageThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  ui.Image image;

  ImageThumbShape({required this.image});

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return const Size(0, 0);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
        required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        required bool isDiscrete,
        required TextPainter labelPainter,
        required RenderBox parentBox,
        required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        required TextDirection textDirection,
        required double value,
        required double textScaleFactor,
        required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final imageWidth = image.width;
    final imageHeight = image.height;
    Offset imageOffset =
    Offset(center.dx - (imageWidth / 2), center.dy - (imageHeight / 2));
    Paint paint = Paint()..filterQuality = FilterQuality.high;
    canvas.drawImage(image, imageOffset, paint);
  }
}
```

[image: Sample output here]